# Vue.js - Highmaps - change variable's value from inside chart

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highmaps

First of all let me introduce you to my project. I am desining a web application that will show some data about devices scattered around a country. To create this I used Vue.js and HighCharts (HighMaps for the map part). This is the result I have achieved now.

[image]

What I want to add now is the possibility for the end-user to click on a marked region and show all of the devices in that region. To do that I need the region's "ID", called code in HighMaps, to send a ajax request to my db and I would also like to make this new "div" a component so that I can use it freely in my application. I'll put a sketch image of what I mean (excuse me for my really bad paint skills :D):

[image]

The black lines are not important, what I would like to achieve is to show a new component besides the map (or wherever really). Next is my current code, I am using the one page, one component style so both *template* and *script* tags are in the same file and I omitted in the *script* tag all the unecessary things. Right now I just set up a div with curly brackets to update a variable on change, just to debug more easily. My main problem is that, in the **plotOptions.series.point.events.click** when I try to reference the **this.foo** variable it doesn't set it since the div doesn't update. I think that might be a scope issue but I wouldn't know where to start looking.

```
<template>
  <div id="canvasContainer">
    <highmaps :options="chartOptions"></highmaps>
    <app-componentForDevices><app-componentForDevices>
    <div>{{foo}}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import HighCharts from 'vue-highcharts';
  import json from '../map.json'

  export default {
    data: function () {
      return {
        foo: 'NO',
        /* Map */
        chartOptions: {
          chart: {
            map: json, // The map data is taken from the .json file imported above
          },
          plotOptions: {
            series: {
              point: {
                events: {
                  click: function () {
                    this.foo='OK'
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            map: {
              joinBy: ['hc-key', 'code'],
              allAreas: false,
              tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '',
                pointFormat: '{point.name}: <b>{series.name}</b>'
              },
            }
          },
          /* Zoom and move */
          mapNavigation: {
            enabled: true,
            buttonOptions: {
              verticalAlign: 'bottom'
            }
          },
          series: [
            {
              allAreas: true,
              showInLegend: false,
            },
            {
              borderColor: '#a0451c',
              cursor: 'pointer',
              name: 'ERROR',
              color: "red",
              data: ['it-na', 'it-mi', 'it-mo', 'it-ud'].map(function (code) {
                return {code: code};
              }),
            },
            {
              borderColor: '#a09e21',
              cursor: 'pointer',
              name: 'WARNING',
              color: "yellow",
              data: ['it-ts', 'it-av', 'it-ri'].map(function (code) {
                return {code: code};
              }),
            },
            {
              borderColor: '#4ea02a',
              cursor: 'pointer',
              name: "OK",
              color: "lightgreen",
              data: ['it-pa', 'it-ve', 'it-bo', 'it-ta', 'it-pn'].map(function (code) {
                return {code: code};
              }),
            },
          ],
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  svg{
    align-items: center;
  }
```

Thanks in advance for the help. Cheers!

### EDIT

I have just tried @icecream_hobbit 's suggestion and using a ECMA6 arrow function helped since now I can access the variable store in Vue but now I lost the access to the local arguments like `this.name` which made possibile for me to print the selected region. Any ideas? Am I missing something?

### EDITv2

Thanks to @icecream_hobbit I have found a way to do what I wanted. You just need to add an object inside the parenthesis so that you can use `this` for the global variable and `e` for your mouse click event.

```
events: {
           click: (e) => {
             this.foo = 'OK'
             this.foo = e.point.name
           }
}
```

Comment: `I try to reference the this.foo variable it doesn't set it since the div doesn't update`  What div are you talking about?

Comment: As you can see from the code above, inside the `<template>` tag, I added a `<div>{{foo}}</div>` under the component I wanted to show. This was done for testing purposes, to make clear and easy to see the point that it doesn't update

Comment: Sorry just now I saw I made a typo, now it should be all good.

Comment: If that hasn't fixed the problem, try declaring `click: () => {this.foo = 'OK'}`

Comment: Well, the typo was just in the example I copy-pasted in here but yet, your "fix" worked quite well indeed, I thought I would have had to do some sort of strange changes to the code but it was just a ECMA6 arrow function :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

> Until arrow functions, every new function defined its own this value
>   (a new object in the case of a constructor, undefined in strict mode
>   function calls, the base object if the function is called as an
>   "object method", etc.)

The `this` you were accessing did not belong to the Vue instance.  You can use an arrow function `() => {/*function body*/}` to inherit the `this` of the Vue instance.

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function
>   expression and does not have its own this, arguments, super, or
>   new.target.

EDIT: For the added question of how do I do I get the Vue instance, and the object instance at the same time you can use a closure.

```
click: function(VueInstance){
    return function() {
        VueInstance.Foo = 'OK';
    }(this)
}
```

Comment: I tried it but now I can access the global Vue variable but I don't have anymore the object that comes with Highmaps click(). See the edit I made to the original post to understand better.
Anyway if you can give me a good answer for this problem too, the green tick is yours

Comment: Thanks for the effort and the patience, you cleared up all my doubts even though the last one I figured it out by myself ;P 
Cheers!